# How do I add up a team's scores?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I am using the `/scoreboard` command. I have everything working, but I would like not only all the players' individual scores on the sideboard, but also the two teams. I would like them to update constantly or if necessary, per second. There are two teams: blue and red, and every time someone presses certain buttons, they trigger command blocks that add one point to their individual scores.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Every second, on some kind of clock, activate the following commands, in this order:

```
/scoreboard players set Red points 0
/scoreboard players operation Red points += @a[team=Red] points
```

Where points is your scoreboard objective. You will also need to do this for Blue.

Comment: Thanks!! Being a developer I was hoping to write some loop for myself